# GetResourceStream returns null halfway when saving image files into Isolated Storage

Tags: c#, image, null, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am trying to save several image files from my XAP into the isolated storage using the following code. I plan to save around 100 files. The problem is the line

```
sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri)
```

returns null half way. Is there a limit as to the number of files the emulator can save? Or may be I'm missing something..

```
    private static void SaveImageFileToIsoStore()
    {

        string[] files = AllFilesInImagesCatFolder();

        using (var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (!isoStore.FileExists(files[0]))
            {
                foreach (string f in files)
                {
                    IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = isoStore.CreateFile(f);
                    StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
                    Uri uri = new Uri("Images/cat/" + f, UriKind.Relative);
                    Debug.WriteLine(f);
                    sri = Application.GetResourceStream(uri);

                    BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
                    bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
                    WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

                    // Encode WriteableBitmap object to a JPEG stream.
                    Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

                    fileStream.Close();
                    fileStream.Dispose();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. Two of the files have a png and jpeg extensions. The code is expecting jpg extension only so it returns null when it encounters those extensions.